# Склонение фамилии Запаренчук

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Склоняется ли фамилия мужского рода Запаренчук?

Comment: Мужского рода? А это как?

Answer (score 1):

Все мужские фамилии, **оканчивающиеся на согласный,** в русском языке склоняются — как существительные второго склонения мужского рода (например, слово "барчук").
Единственное исключение — фамилии на **-ых, -их** типа *Черных, Долгих*.
Все женские фамилии на согласный не склоняются.

[Как склонять фамилии (трудные случаи)](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/71-rubric-482)

И. п. (кто?) барчук, Ковальчук, Запаренчук
Р. п. (кого?) барчука, Ковальчука, Запаренчука
Д. п. (кому?) барчуку, Ковальчуку, Запаренчуку
В. п. (кого?) барчука, Ковальчука, Запаренчука
Т. п. (кем?) барчуком, Ковальчуком, Запаренчуком
П. п. (о ком?) о барчуке, о Ковальчуке, о Запаренчуке

[Склонение фамилий на **-чук**](http://gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%87%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0)